# Export CSV on basis of filters set in php

Tags: php

I am trying to download a csv file. I have implemented the following code and it works fine to download/export all the records as csv. But I have filters on the page. So I want to add the functionality to it like, to export the records as csv according to the filter selected. How can I do that in php ?

Here is the code:

**index.php**

```
<form id="filters">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            Filter by School:
            <select name="school">
                <option disabled selected>Select School</option>
                <? foreach($model->schools AS $school) { ?>
                    <option value="<?=$school->id?>" <?= isset($_GET['school']) && $_GET['school'] == $school->id?'selected':'' ?>>
                        <?=$school->name?>
                    </option>
                <? } ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <a href="<?= /students/export">Export CSV</a>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#filters :input').change(function(e){
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

**studentscontroller.php**

**Edited**

```
class studentsController extends mainController{
function index(Array $params = []){
    $this->_viewData->schools = \Model\School::getList();
    $schoolSql = '';
    if(isset($_GET['school']) && $_GET['school'] != ''){
        $sql = "school_id = {$_GET['school']}";
    }

    $params['queryOptions']['where'] = "$sql"; //This will be 'select * from students where $sql' 
    parent::index($params);
}

function export(Array $params = []){
    $this->template = false;

    $this->_viewData->students = \Model\Student::getList(['where'=>"status="active"]);
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=students_record.csv');
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $t=array("Name",'Email','School','Year');
    fputcsv($output, $t);
    $row ='';
    foreach($this->_viewData->students as $obj) {
        $school = \Model\School::getItem($obj->school_id);
        $row = array($obj->name,$obj->email,$school->name,$obj->year);
        fputcsv($output, $row);  
    }   
    parent::index($params);
}
}
```

I know may be its possible to pass `$_GET` values as link parameter but how to do that ? Also may be I can get the selected value from the dropdown and pass that value to the export function, but don't know how to do that ?

Help is really appreciated. TIA.

Comment: in your for loop `if($obj->school_id != $_GET['school']) continue;` is probably enough

Comment: For that first we need to pass `$_GET['school']` to that function. How to pass that $_GET through params ?

Comment: beware mysql injections though! your line `$sql = "school_id = {$_GET['school']}";` looks awfully like one waiting to happen. to answer your question: you have to set the method of your form to 'get', alternatively use `$_REQUEST['school']` to be on the convenient side.

Answer (score 0):

Jakumi's comment is correct, just change this:

```
foreach($this->_viewData->students as $obj) {
    $school = \Model\School::getItem($obj->school_id);
    $row = array($obj->name,$obj->email,$school->name,$obj->year);
    fputcsv($output, $row);  
}
```

To this

```
foreach($this->_viewData->students as $obj) {
    if($obj->school_id != $_GET['school']) continue;
    $school = \Model\School::getItem($obj->school_id);
    $row = array($obj->name,$obj->email,$school->name,$obj->year);
    fputcsv($output, $row);  
}
```

You will also need to change the form opening element to specify the `action` and `method` attributes, so this:

```
<form id="filters">
```

...becomes this:

```
<form id="filters" action='./path/to/generate.csv' method='get'>
```

Comment: I am submitting the form on change of filter values, in my code I have a javascript function which submits the function and will go to the index(). While my export function is another function which generates csv file. Son't think I have to add any action or method as my frameworks do that automatically.

Comment: Also I can't use `$_GET['school']` in my `export()` function without passing that values to the function.

Comment: You _can_ still use `$_GET['school']` in the `export()` function _if the URL which calls the export function has `?school=something` in the URL_.  This document should help you: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: And the jQuery you have which is submitting your form is still _submitting your form_, so the `method` and `action` attributes may still be needed.

Comment: I am not getting `?school=something` in the URL. That is what I am asking about how to pass that value to URL

Comment: And `Form` is for the filters. And through the framework we are using, once I select the filter, it will automatically go to the desired function and do the action. So not to worry about method and action

Comment: You can either (1) submit the form (which is what you're doing now) in which case it will follow the attributes (the `method` and `action` I provided) of that form, or (2) you can use JavaScript to open a new window with values set in the URL of the form itself, ex: `window.location = './path/to/something?school='+jQuery("#school").val();`